# Why does Java's BigInteger have TEN and ONE as constants? Any Practical use?

Tags: java

Why does BigInteger class has constant TEN and ONE? Any practical uses for having them as constants?  I can understand some use cases for ZERO.

Comment: kind of important numbers in general, aren't they?

Comment: @Denis Tulskiy: I'm with the OP on this. ZERO is the most important number followed by ONE. TEN is a rank outsider as it's just a curiosity of an arbitrary radix.

Comment: I don't understand what's special about the number 00001010.

Comment: What's special about it is, it's not valid in a BigInteger. It would be represented as 00010000 instead.

Comment: @Ben 00010000? Wait, what? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I am just interested in knowing the practical uses of ONE and TEN constants from BigInteger.

Comment: i've often used ZERO, ONE and TEN in quite some programs i wrote. don't recall the cases. just like some programmers are forced to use 0, 1 and 10 at times ;) ...anyways, fun to watch the outcome of this :D

Comment: ZERO and ONE are special values in any integer system, and TEN is very useful if you're displaying values to or reading values from users who are mainly experienced with the normal arabic numeral system. Like _virtually all_ real users…

Comment: I came here for the wrong reasons, nobody's talking about me. :P

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Let's say you have written a function that returns `BigInteger` after some calculations and db operations. You often may need to return values like null, 0, 1. It's easy to return `BigInteger.ZERO`. This values are public since they are needed **commonly**.

```
public BigInteger findMyLovelyBigInteger(Integer secretNumber) {
    if (secretNumber == null) {
        return BigInteger.ZERO; // better than BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    } else {
        // some db operations
    }
}
```

Also `BigInteger.TEN` is commonly used for power/divide/mod operations.

Checkout `BigInteger` public methods. You will easily see their common use cases.

Comment: so where is BigInteger.TEN used in BigInteger public methods?

Comment: As it is written on answer, BigInteger.TEN is commonly used for power/divide/mod operations.

Comment: Why would you use BigInteger.TEN instead of 10?

Comment: @Andy if you're dealing with BigInteger objects already, using the defined constant could save from the need of autoboxing/unboxing and the creation of a new object. Could possibly be of benefit if used thousands of times in some loop.

Comment: @Andy because `BigInteger.TEN` is a lot more clear than `BigInteger.valueOf(10)`. Especially if you `import static` it.

Comment: @DrakeClarris I don't think so. If you use `BigInteger` you expect numbers to be *big*, hence you already expect that any operation on them is "heavy", so I doubt that the overhead of autoboxing etc. would be a bottleneck.

Comment: @Bakuriu Oh I agree. Premature optimization... you know the rest. Just trying to throw an idea out there. Compiler probably makes it a moot point anyways.

Comment: @Bakuriu On the other hand if the operations are known to be "heavy", anything that helps make them a little lighter may be a plus. Essentially, if you're in a loop than runs for many iterations, you want to avoid creating lots of unnecessary objects since this stresses the garbage collector. If you run a million iterations of a loop which needs 10 as the basis of logarithm or something similar, the cost of creating and garbage collecting a million objects each representing "10" may be significant.

Comment: BigInteger.valueOf(0) doesn't cause an object to be created (or for any number from -16 to 16).  There might be a little overhead from making the method call, but it would be inlined in a loop.  The only real benefit is a slight gain in readability.

Comment: @MichałKosmulski: Of course, in such a case you could precreate the "10" object yourself; it wouldn't have to be a static field of the `BigInteger` class.

Answer (score 21):

**One** is probably the most fundamental number in mathematics (alongside zero). Seems to deserve its own constant on that alone. Practically, it's a useful number to have as a constant in many algorithms.

**Ten** is important in the BigInteger context because it is the base of the decimal number system. This is important because several BigInteger functions need a radix base (e.g. `BigInteger.toString(int radix)`. It's therefore a pretty useful constant to have.

Comment: Except that `TEN` is a `BigInteger`, not an int, so for those methods it'd be of no use at all.

Comment: I'm assuming it's being used internally in radix-related functions....

Comment: There would be no need for a *public* constant, then, if it's only used internally.

Comment: If TEN is being used internally, why make it public?

Comment: @cx0der: why not make it public?

Comment: @Denis Without an explicit need, why should anything need to be public?

Comment: @cx0der The explicit need is to reuse existing value objects.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: BigIntegers from -16 to 16 are cached anyway. I think it is more for clarity. TEN is a common constant, and BigInteger.TEN looks better than BigInteger.valueOf(10)

Comment: BigInteger.TEN is faster than BigInteger.valueOf(10);

Comment: @DenisTulskiy They may be cached *today*, but were they cached in 1996, when Java 1.1 came out? Because *that's* how ridiculous it is to bother seriously answering this question.

Comment: The question deserves a serious answer, even if the answer is just "for historical reasons."

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I recently examined the javadocs.  It says BigInteger was from 1.1; ZERO and ONE were from 1.2; and TEN was from 1.5.  I did not know BigIntegers from -16 to 16 are cached or when they started being cached.  Anyway your comment should be were they cached since 1998 and/or 2004 when versions 1.2 and 1.5 came out.

Comment: @emory That at least makes this more interesting because if it was such a late addition, there must have been a good reason.

Comment: @emory It just so happens that `BigDecimal` got the `TEN` constant, along with `ZERO` and `ONE`, in the Tiger release. This sounds like a motivation from consistency of API.

Answer (score 11):

IMHO that was a design decision because 1 and 10 are used in other parts of the Java API code base. Creating Big* is an expensive operation and using constant avoid new object creation (Big* are immutable anyway) and the code is more readable.

Probably other constants weren't needed by the rest of the API.

Making them public was probably a fault. (The java API is full of "bad" design decisions)

Comment: Unfortunately, BigIntegers are not immutable. Hope this gets fixed sometimes.

Comment: @Ingo Could you elaborate on this? The Javadoc starts with "Immutable arbitrary-precision integers."

Comment: Well it seems it is better protected now in JDK7, but I think I remember having seen the constituting fields visible (so that one could, for instance, change the mag array). Anyway, for full immutability the class should be final and any fields private. (Still, mutation through reflection is still possible, just like with String)

Comment: +1 for correct answer; the answer is "for performance"...

Comment: @Ingo As far as I can tell, BigInteger does not have any mutator methods or public fields (other than static constants) in any version of the JDK. This also prevents you from making it mutable through inheritance, so it doesn't really need to be final.

Comment: @Taymon if this is so, then I have erred.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know actually, but maybe:

- zero: [additive identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_identity)
- one: [multiplicative identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_identity)
- ten: radix of the decimal system

Maybe they just used these constans a lot internally? (I haven't checked the source code, but it's Open Source).

**Edit:**

E.g.:

After looking at the code I think the reason is because they use ZERO and ONE a lot internally. Probably thought that others might profit from these constants as well given the reasons above. Or maybe they use these constants in some other classes as well.

TEN has been added in v1.5
It doesn't seem to be used internally, but maybe by another class?

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java

Comment: Likely cause its wrong, seems the right answer is something to do with the fact that 0 != ZERO and 10 != TEN

Comment: @paulm Since OP seems to understand the need for ZERO as a constant, the fact the ZERO != 0 or TEN != 10 **is not at all relevant**.

Comment: Harshal Patil has not mentioned that *anywhere* in the question, he wants to know why these constants are defined

Comment: @paulm `"I can understand some use cases for ZERO."`

Comment: Not +1 because if it were only used internally it would've been `private` (it could be **part of** the argument, but not the main argument). And I think you kind of lost the plot by saying `TEN` may be used by another class (presumably in the API) (in which case it would've been `protected`).

Comment: @paulm but they are the BigInteger representation of these values.

Comment: TEN is used in BigDecimal

Comment: @Dukeling "would've been private" or "could've been private" is the question. ;-) Maybe it just was decided that other might find these useful as well (they are immutable and thus it doesn't make sense to have several instances for the same value - especially for common ones)

Answer (score -2):

10, 0 and 1 can answer almost everything. for example if you want to arrive at 42, you can do a (10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 1 + 1) :)

Comment: But I can arrive at this using valueof(42)

Comment: lol a sense of humour on stack overflow? surely not!